# AngularJS bindonce directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple directive for calculating "ago"

```
.directive('ago', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            time: '@'
        },         
        template: '<span class="time">{{ calculateTime(time) }}</span>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.calculateTime = function(timestamp)
            {


<ago time="{{ status.time }}"></ago>
```

Works great. **But I would like to bind it once and then destroy it for performance reasons.**

I have tried:

```
    link: function( $scope ) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$destroy();
        }, 0);
    }
```

Because I found it somewhere in past, dont remember exactly. But with this link the directive is not working and it's printed actually {{ calculateTime(time) }} without error in console.

Any idea?

Comment: Basically you want to destroy the watch? so it is not part of digest cycle anymore right?. You could use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) so that watches on calculateTime is destroyed after the intial load.

Comment: @PSL Or you can use [the core "one-time binding" feature](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)…

Comment: @Blackhole Yeah, right only if you are in 1.3

Comment: I am not. If I tried to apply bind-once attribute to my directive I got an error: Multiple directives are requiring isolated scope.

Comment: I tried that but it throws weird errors as its expecting something else not a function...

Comment: @Trki Can you prepare a plnkr?

Comment: Sure. Something like that? http://plnkr.co/edit/HIUnRcg9ZpNAFoz7OgAH?p=preview I am not sure if everything is setup correctly as my eye are closing now :) ... I will check it on morning again but the most important code is there now.

Comment: @Trki Here is an example.. http://jsbin.com/gokoqaji/2/edit In your examle it throws error since you have not defined a controller called `IndexCtrl`

Comment: @PSL okay, there is something super strange going on... I have the exact same code in my app but it's not printing anything when I pass the value through time = ... only when I manually modified return "something". As I said will check it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Bind-once or one time bind using :: is all about binding your model once.

So if you are 1.3 and used { ::calculateTime(time)}} your directive linking will be still part of the cycle as you figured out.

Your link destroy will not work like that because the calculateTime in

{{ calculateTime(time)}}

does not exist now hence how it is printed. This is not an error condition from Angular's perspective. Although in the link fn you may just replace the HTML with the precomputed value of the earlier results of calculateTime() i.e.
 essentially replace {{ calculateTime(time)}} with  the results.

But all this seems convoluted way of achieving what you may be trying to achieve. 
Wondering why you can't use a simple filter with one time bind

http://plnkr.co/edit/ugjx4vlXtLu95IuBz7yv?p=preview

```
.filter('calcTime',function() {

  return function(input) {
    return input - 2;
  };
})
```